# How do I activate a spinner in an accessory title bar view controller from different class?

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit, nstitlebaraccessoryviewcontroller

I've got an `NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController` with an indeterminate `NSProgressIndicator` in it. I want to be able to start and stop it from different places in my application, sometimes outside of a view controller.

I'm fairly new to OS X development.
I heard that in OS X the responder chain more used than in iOS. I have looked into the responder chain and how to do this via `NSResponder`, but I really can't make any sense of it. Below is a screenshot for visualisation.

[image]

Here is the code for my title bar acc. view controller:

```
class TitleBarAccessoryViewController: NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController, TitleBarActionable {

@IBOutlet var loadingSpinner: NSProgressIndicator!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do view setup here.
}
func loadingSpinnerShouldBecomeActive(activate: Bool) {
    print("Hello")
    loadingSpinner.hidden = !activate
    if activate {
        loadingSpinner.startAnimation(self)
    } else {
        loadingSpinner.stopAnimation(self)
    }
  }
}
```

I'm then want to call it via a protocol extension:

```
extension EmployeeAPI {

    func getAllEmployees(completionHandler: ([FDataSnapshot]) -> Void) {
        let employeeRef = ref.childByAppendingPath("employees")
        //Somehow start the loading indicator here

        employeeRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
            //And somehow stop it here
            var arr: [FDataSnapshot] = []
            for snap in snapshot.children {
                if let snap = snap as? FDataSnapshot {
                    arr.append(snap)
                }
            }
            completionHandler(arr)
        })
```

I am also looking to start and stop it from different viewControllers, so it is not confined to protocol extensions.

Comment: I've seen NSNotificationCenter is fairly common to use in this case. Just create custom event and spawn it listening in TitleBarAccessoriyViewController. However, if you keep having such situations, it is better to take another look at the application architecture and use something like Application Controller pattern or VIPER pattern, to build complex app. Massive View Controller architecture may be not the best choice for such apps.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly besides your question - but the **responder chain** is a very common [design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern) and if you're planning to stick around in software development this is absolutely worth a read:

- **Responder Chain** a.k.a. **Chain-of-responsibility** pattern, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern
- **Cocoa Design Patterns**, [Chain of Responsibility design pattern](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW25)

Comment: Thanks Jay. I'll look into that

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward solution that is decoupled is to use an `NSNotification` with e.g. "TitleBarAccessoryViewStartSpinnerNotification" and "TitleBarAccessoryViewStopSpinnerNotification".